# What are the pros/cons of iterating an array with Array.prototype.forEach() versus for() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

What are the pros/cons of iterating an array with Array.prototype.forEach() versus for() in Javascript?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/75

Comment: forEach not supported by IE<9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forEach` looks better sometimes and can avoid intermediate variables and closure problems.

`for` is faster, works on non-arrays, maintains `this` by default, and has always been part of JavaScript. You can also break out of it with `break;` — even nested.

In ES6, `forEach`’s `this`-maintaining and looks are improved by the introduction of `=>`; `for`’s verbosity and sometimes unintuitive scope is improved by `let` and `for of` loops.

As 6502 answered, they work differently on sparse arrays.
Do not use sparse arrays.

Answer (score 2):

They do two very different things:

1. `for (var i=0; i<L.length; i++) { ... }` iterates over ALL indexes, including array elements that "are undefined".
2. `forEach` iterates only on defined elements.

Note also that being "undefined" doesn't simply mean that the **value** of an element is `undefined`, but that the element as never been set and the two are very different things:

```
a = [];
a[3] = 9;
a.indexOf(undefined) // --> -1
a[1] = undefined;
a.indexOf(undefined) // --> 1
```

so you can have a defined element with value `undefined`...

```
a = [];
a[9] = 9;
a[3] = undefined;

a.forEach(function(){ console.log(arguments); });
```

will show two lines, one for element with index 9 and one for element with index 3

Answer (score 0):

Beware of `Array.prototype.forEach()` if you're planning on using any polyfills/shims to provide prototype functionality to older browsers (I'm looking at you, InternetExplorer).

For example, the `toString()` method isn't available for arrays in older versions of IE. I have a polyfill that adds the `toString()` method to the Array.prototype in order for my application to work in older browsers. However, iterating with the `.forEach()` iterator also has access to (and will indeed iterate over) that method, in addition to iterating over the contents of your array.

In general though, `for` is much faster.  If have JSON objects you'd like to loop through though, `forEach` is godsend.